# Streaming video(movie) using c#

Tags: c#, sockets, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I want to create project as server to stream movie with audio but I don't have to create client project 
I  mean I need to make this project avalible to be usful to any client like (IP Video Transcoding Live) application 
but I don't care about resolution or protocol that I use
I just want to stream movie from specific location in my device to port and then to client like vlc (for instance) so I want to create server project without client 
Are there any libraries usful to create this project or could anyone tell my the steps to do it ?

Comment: You want to create a pipe which is just a Stream class.  You can use a MemoryStream Class.

Comment: I want to stream  video from my device to network port